# Process Explorer Why is my Java process displayed with a shortcut icon?

Tags: java, process-explorer

Why is my Java process displayed with a shortcut icon?

I have startade the Java program from a bat-file containing this command:

```
java -jar myProgram.jar
```

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it is because the Java icon itself was someone build with the shortcut overlay embedded.

Comment: @music2myear Other Java processes is not displayed with the shortcut icon.

Comment: What is the process's command line?